# What datatype/structure to store file list info?

Tags: delphi, data-structures, tree, directory

I have an application that searches files on the computer (configurable path, type etc). Currently it adds information to a database as soon as a matching file is found. Rather than that I want to hold the information in memory for further manipulation before inserting to database. The list may contain a lot of items. I consider performance as important factor. I may need iterating thru the items, so a structure that can be coded easily is another key issue. and how can I achieve php style associative arrays for this job?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Delphi 2009, you can use a TDictionary.  It takes two generic parameters.  The first should be a string, for the filename, and the second would be whatever data type you're associating with.  It also has three built-in enumerators, one for key-value pairs, one for keys only and one for values only, which makes iterating easy.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be to use just a standard TStringList.

As long as it's sorted and has some duplicate setting other than dupAccept, you can use indexof or indexofname to find items in the list quickly.

It also has the Objects addition which allows you to store object information attached to the name.  Starting with D2009, TStringList has the OwnsObject property which allows you to delegate object cleanup to the TStringList.  Prior to D2009 you have to handle that yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Much of this will depend on how you are going to use the list and to what scale.  If you are going to use it as a stack, or queue, then a TList would work fine.  If your needing to search through the list for a specific item then you will need something that allows faster retrieval.  TDictionary (2009) or TStringList (pre 2009) would be the most likely choice.

Dynamic arrays are also a possiblity, but if you use them you will want to minimize the use of SetLength as each time it is called it will re-allocate memory.  TList manages this for you, which is why I suggested using a TList.  if you KNOW how many you will deal with in advance, then use a dynamic array, and set its length on the onset.

If you have more items than will fit in memory then your choices also change.  At that point I would either use a database table, or a tFileStream to store the records to be processed, then seek to the beginning of the table/stream for processing.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the AVL-Tree by http://sourceforge.net/projects/alcinoe/ as your associative Array. It has an iterate-method for fast iteration. You may need to derive from his baseclass and implement your own comparator, but it's easy to use.

Examples are included.